# SQL Query - Getting the sum of different varchar values

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay so I have a string stored as a column in a database, for simplicity sake lets say the database looks something like this:

```
id - string
0    string1
1    string1
2    string1
3    string2
4    string1
5    string3
```

How exactly would I write a query to list out each string that is in the string column and how many rows has that value. For example in this case, it would look like this:

```
string - count
string1  4
string2  1
string3  1
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT string, count(*) as count 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT string, Count(*) as Count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY string
```

BTW, what you have shown is a table rather than a database. Also, `string` is a very poor name for a column.

Comment: Yeah sorry, meant it was in a table in a database. Also I just used string to make it simple to understand, I don't really have much experience with databases though, just know basic SQL stuff. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Also, if I had a second column that was a string, is there an easy way I can add up the counts for both columns like in the original query, but then divide them by each other. For example there is a table with id - string1 - string2, in string1 there are 5 "Blaf", in string 2 there are 2 "Blaf", so then it divides them and outputs Blaf - 2.5000